# Can two proteins activate/inhibit the same gene at the same time?

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, bioinformatics, proteins, gene

Suppose there are two proteins inhibiting a particular gene. Its not necessary that both will inhibit the gene at the same time instance right?
So if one protein has already inhibited that gene before the other protein, what is left for the other protein to inhibit this gene? It has already been inhibited right? What more does the other protein inhibit?

Comment: Probably the proteins are competing (like a % downregulation) to bind at the gene or they bind at different parts of the gene? it depends, do you refer to a specific example?

Comment: Inhibition does not necessarily need to be competitive, i.e. in the same place, i.e. the inhibitors work on different targets at the same time. Inhibition also need not be 'total', it can be partial. The inhibitors can be partial, additive or even synergistic (joint inhibition is greater than the sum inhibition of its parts). Single inhibitors can also sometimes inhibit multiple targets, so any 'extra leftover' inhibitors can work on other targets. Or work at different times in development; i.e. an inhibitor can have different targets in the embryo vs. the adult, or in tissue A vs. tissue B.

Comment: Can you give me a link to study more about inhibitors? These information that you gave me,  would these be available from any source?

Comment: This is general information available in any biochemistry or molecular biology textbook. I think you could start with Wikipedia, it has pages upon pages on molecular inhibition. A good starting point would be [enzyme inhibition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enzyme_inhibitor). Though many targets or processes can be inhibited - not only singular enzymes - such as the transcription of genes, or the progression of the cell into the next phase of its cell cycle, or the polarization of cells, and so on and so forth.

Comment: the inhibitors work on different targets at the same time.- does this mean multiple molecule of the inhibitor is in action at this time?

Comment: Are you referring to protein inhibition at transcription/ replication level or in general?     As you are mentioning the effect of protein on gene?

Comment: @Twinkle in general

Comment: Then its already explained in comment section. If you are particularly concerned at DNA level, then there are different proteins like transcription factors which bind to upstream elements located on DNA and regulate the DNA transcription.